# Scan numeric values in strings c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `string rx;`
and this string has the following type of data: "v=123.111i=10.123r=1234\r\n"

So, what I want: 
-have a 3 floating point(or some other decimal var)  variables, "v" i" and "r".
-scan the string... with a format string like "v=%.3fi=%.3fr=%.3f\r\n" where %.3f is the value (3 decimal digits)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://WhatHaveYouTried.com)

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regex` and `Double.Parse`:

```
var inputString = @"v=123.111i=10.123r=1234\r\n";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\d+[.]?\d{3}"))
{
    double result = Double.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

explain:

```
\d+          digits (0-9) 
             (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

[.]?         character of: '.' 
             (optional, matching the most amount possible)

\d{3}        digits (0-9) 
             (3 times)
```

and I used [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx). It converts the `string` representation of a number to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`var result = Regex.Matches(rx, @"\d+([,.]\d{1,3})?");`

Comment: I'm sorry for what I'm about to say, I'm really a noob in C#...
Can that "var result" be a double?

Comment: This var will become a type returned by Regex.Matches method, which is MatchCollection, hence the result will become an object of type MatchCollection. Having this collection you will still have to iterate through it and cast the values to double.